Movies that are closed loops
In the movie Lost Highway, Fred Madison receives a message from an unknown man on the intercom of the front door of his house saying, "Dick Laurent is dead." At the end of the movie we see him giving this message to himself causing a strange loop.
I'm more aware of this happening in literary fiction with Finnegans Wake being a prime example. 
Are there more movies where the end of the movie is the beginning of the movie? I've not seen many. Is this a "trope?"
Things like Memento, that are told out of order, do not count. Only movies that lap themselves and create a loop are my interest here. 
(PS - I only used identify-this-movie because I could not find a better tag and didn't think this question warranted making a new one.)

Off-Topic? ... Isn't this asking for a list?

"I only used identify-this-movie because I could not find a better tag" - Maybe because it's hard to say what the goal of the question is. Apart from that, Triangle comes to mind.

I haven't seen Triangle yet. Does it end where it starts and start where it ends? Is it a loop? (I know spoilers are implicit in this question.)

@Paulster2 Not asking for a list. Just asking if there are other movies like this. One example would be welcome, two would be generous, but I'm not asking for a list. I just couldn't think of another movie like this off the top of my head at this moment.

@NapoleonWilson I thought it was clear. Are there any other movies where the end of the movie is the beginning of the movie ala Lost Highway.

@MeatTrademark Well, yes there are, but I'm not sure that would make for a great answer (and would probably inspire more equally invaluable "here's a nice example"-answers, as a "proper" list question does). The question could deserve much better answers, but I'm also not sure how to reword it in order to motivate those, as it's unclear to me what it is you're actually after (apart from the listy "just another example"-aspect). But for now I'm also not sure if to close it and would rather wait if maybe someone comes up with a valuable answer before making that decision.

Okay. My hat is in the ring. Can anyone name TWO movies that are closed loops. @NapoleonWilson You sound like you have examples but are holding back. Does 2 examples count as a list? The end of the movie is the beginning of the movie. I can't make it much more clear than that.

@MeatTrademark And regarding Triangle, it ends exactly where it starts. Yet it's rather the next iteration of an endless loop of the exact same events. But the movie would go exactly as it did if it continued after the end.

@MeatTrademark Haha, and the answer that gives 2 would lead to a question for 3? ;-) But I'll see if I could back up Triangle with some more elaborations on the background of such loops, as just posting an example-answer would feel downright stupid to me (and warrant a list-close even more).

@MeatTrademark ... you are also asking for recommendations.

Donnie Darko comes to mind. Twelve Monkeys also contains the loop, but I'm not sure if time travelling is what you're looking for.

Oh, and DoodleBug by Christopher Nolan is probably the shortest loop in cinema history :)

http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/18202/3552

The 1972 Solaris?

@defaultlocale 12 Monkeys contains a loop, but the movie does not start where it ends. Same with Donnie Darko since he stays in bed for the next loop, closing it. And DoodleBug didn't loop on itself either. And Napoleon, I actually already owned the DVD of Triangle but hadn't watched it yet. That's a closed loop all right. Thanks. (I know it sounds like I wanted recommendations to watch, but it was really just curiosity if this had happened much in film. Now I know it happened at least in Triangle and Salvage. Seems like it'd be more common.)

It's a common enough plot device and I've provided two examples below. The first one's an older film (from the 1960s) and the second one is fairly recent (mid 2000s). 
Also, just to demonstrate how different genres can adopt the plot device, the first example is a genuine science-fiction film while the second one is a horror movie.
The Time Travelers (1964)

In 1964, a group of scientists create a portal that takes them to a
  barren, mutant inhabited, Earth in the year 2071.

The twist ending (spoilers):

 However, in the last quarter, Ib Melchior [the director] brings The Time Travelers to a remarkable ending where the time travelers return through the portal only to find the world moving 100 times slower than they are and watch themselves starting the entire process off again, then traveling through the portal a second time and becoming caught up in an endless loop. 

Salvage (2006)

Claire Parker is going to die. At the hands of a sadistic and depraved
  killer, she will endure a terrifying, unimaginable brutal death--and
  it will all happen again. After being beaten, dragged, sliced, and
  stabbed, Claire awakens at work--where it all began--untouched and
  unharmed. But the hellish ordeal is far from over. The madman is back
  and he's ready for more blood...

The twist ending (spoilers):

The girl we saw was actually the killer in hell... his punishment was reliving her last day and her gruesome death over and over again for eternity. When she steps out of the shower we see him as her reflection, and at the end of the movie the mother tells her, "You are not my daughter, you killed my daughter". So we see the girl turn into the killer being skinned by himself... exactly where the movie started, in the basement. Hence, the reliving. =) 

P.S. There are many more examples out there, but I should probably charge you a bounty before I list those :-)

Salvage sounds like the movie loops (so the check and +1 were for that), but the first example just sounds like it has loops. (Haven't seen it, so I'm not sure.)
