# A black and white movie about waking up

Tags: identify-this-movie, black-and-white

I recall an old Twilight Zone-type movie which begins with a car driving up to a house. There are a series of events/stories told via the characters in the house but at the end (after some horror-esque events) the central character wakes up and it was all a dream. So the character, now awake, goes to his appointment which involves his driving up to the same house at the end of the movie.

It is a close loop movie inspired by [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18200/movies-that-are-closed-loops) question and I thought I recalled it was called something like "House of" something but House of Games, Cards, Lies all don't seem right.

Comment: Hang on, hang on... You'll get the answer to this question, which you'll post as an answer to the other question, which will give Meat Trademark the answer to his question? Mind = Blown! True Movie-ception going on :) All we need now is for Meat Trademark to realise he only posted the question because of the answer you'll get here and the closed loop is complete!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Dead of Night (1945) - Movie Poster]

[**Dead of Night** (1945)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037635/)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_of_Night), here's the synopsis:

> Architect Walter Craig arrives at a country house party where he
>   reveals to the assembled guests that he has seen them all in a dream.
>   He appears to have no prior personal knowledge of them but he is able
>   to predict spontaneous events in the house before they unfold.
>
> The other guests attempt to test Craig's foresight, while entertaining
>   each other with various tales of uncanny or supernatural events that
>   they experienced or were told about.
>
> These include a racing car driver's premonition of a fatal bus crash;
>   a light hearted tale of two obsessed golfers, one of whom becomes
>   haunted by the other's ghost; a ghostly encounter during a children's
>   Christmas party; a haunted antique mirror; and the story of an
>   unbalanced ventriloquist who believes his amoral dummy is truly alive.
>
> The framing story is then capped by a twist ending.

Read the full summary [here](http://www.screenonline.org.uk/film/id/491909/synopsis.html) and watch some clips [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxYrjz9jQlc), [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qq9RUI4exQk) and [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x18kdna_dead-of-night-1945_shortfilms).

Comment: Brilliant! I am glad to know that I had the "of" right...you should go and use this for the answer to the other question now.

Comment: I like that the movie stars Google Withers.  Erm, I mean, Googie.

Comment: @Dan - Glad to help. Regarding that other post, I thought I'd pick some other movies for my answer :-)

Comment: @mskfisher - Even without the "l", it's still a fun-sounding name :-)